# Rails - Pass multiple checkbox values through params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form, parameters

I am using [Smart listing](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing) gem for real time filtering.
The following is a simple form without a submit and url.

```
<%= smart_listing_controls_for(:search) do %>
  <%= simple_form_for :search do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :certificates, collection: Certificate.all, :as => :check_boxes, include_hidden: false, :input_html => {:multiple => true} %>
  <% end>
<% end>
```

The above code generates multiple check-boxes with 'Certificate id's as values.
As soon as one of the check-boxes is checked, smart listing sends a request to the controller with the params.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_smart_listing"=>{"_"=>"1", "page"=>"", "per_page"=>"10"}, "authenticity_token"=>"z25rULU5JeeWcEZdpsy0+bz7OJFDWPmXrVGnzPvdG0cjM0ufpc3ydB9+5GywDQkUmcm6RGJnF0C4Yrd0sWpJ6g==", "search"=>{ "certificates"=>["6"]}}
```

The problem is when I select multiple check-boxes, the certificates array just has the latest value and not all the selected check-boxes values.

Also, when a check-box is selected and de-selected, the certificates array value in the params remains the same. I want the value to be removed from the certificates array in the params if the check-box is deselected and only want the certificates array to just have all the selected check-boxes values.

The following is the html code generated for one of the multiple check-boxes.

```
<span class="checkbox">
  <label for="search_certificates_5">
    <input class="check_boxes required" type="checkbox" value="5" name="search[certificates][]" id="search_certificates_5">
     Certificate 1
  </label>
</span>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `smart_listing_controls_for` and `simple_form_for` create a **form**, one problem you might have is that you are creating a form inside a form, and that is nor recommended nor standard. That might lead to unexpected results.

Maybe try doing it without the **simple_form** helper, something like this (assuming `Certificate` has a description attribute):

```
<%= smart_listing_controls_for(:search) do %>
  <%= Certificate.all.each do |certificate| %>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class= "checkbox inline">
        <%= check_box_tag 'search[certificates][]', certificate.id %>
        <%= certificate.description %>
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

Also, there's a problem with current release (**v1.1.2**) of the **smart listing** gem that doesn't allow to work with array inputs. Problem is in this part of the [javascript code](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/blob/v1.1.2/app/assets/javascripts/smart_listing.coffee.erb#L364). This is fixed on current master branch and was updated recently on latest commit as you can see [here](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/commit/79adebaeba834c202376b052ae4675916ae06bb3).

To solve this use the latest commit in your **Gemfile** like this:

```
gem 'smart_listing', :git => 'https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing.git', :ref => '79adeba'
```

`bundle install` after updating **Gemfile** and try the above code again.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for the answer. But it didn't work. The same issue as before. Only one value in the certificates array. Here are the params after removing the simple form
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_smart_listing"=>{"_"=>"1", "page"=>"", "per_page"=>"10"}, "search"=>{"certificates"=>["6"]}}`

Comment: @Mahendhar I've updated my answer. You should still use 1 form, but also there's a problem with current release. Check my answer.

Comment: @Mahendhar Hey, Im trying to accomplish something similar where each checkbox  will filter when checked. Currently my checkbox will not un-filter once i uncheck the checkbox and also if i checked more than one checkboxes it will not display the output of all selected checkboxes. Would you be able to guide me to the right. Thanks!!

Comment: @Tim it all depends on how you filter on your controller. Remember that unchecked boxes are not sent on form submit (only checked ones are), so you have to keep that in mind in order to make the right filter.

Comment: @Tim, This is my multiple checkboxes code in the view
`<%= hidden_field_tag 'certificates[]', '' %>
        <% Certificate.all.each do |certificate| %>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class= "checkbox inline">
            <%= check_box_tag 'certificates[]', certificate.id %>
            <%= certificate.title %>
          </label>
        </div>
        <% end %>`

Comment: @Tim, here is my code in the controller.
`search_scope = UserProfile.all
search_scope = search_scope.joins(:certificates).where('certificates.id' => params[:certificates]) if params[:certificates] != nil && params[:certificates] != [""]`

Comment: @Tim, in my app, every user has a user_profile and every user_profile has many certificates. I am filtering all the user_profiles based on the checkboxes checked.

Comment: @Mahendhar Thanks so much for the help! I current have a minor issue.. do you know why does it add `style: opacity: 0.2` to the output whenever i start using the filter?

Comment: @Tim, when you select a filter or click on a pagination link, just before the content is updated, the opacity is applied. 
For ex, go to http://showcase.sology.eu/smart_listing and click on the pagination links on one of the demos.